# AudioKit v4 now has internalAU set to private/

Tags: ios, audiokit

I'm working on my AudioKit app for the first time in nearly a year, so I've had to update my version of AudioKit to v4

In v3 I had been using internalAU.fullStateForDocument on the AKSampler to get at the envelopes, but apparently now internalAU has private protection level.

What is the best way for me to get my hands on this now?

Its also the first Swift programming I've done since then, so I'm a bit rusty, and I may be missing something obvious

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are public properties in `AKSampler` to access all the parameters.

Also, `internalAU` is the same as `avAudioNode.auAudioUnit`, which is also public. So I think you can use something like this:

```
(mySampler.avAudioNode.auAudioUnit as! AKSamplerAudioUnit).fullStateForDocument
```